# Optimized searching in Python against a list

Tags: python, optimization

Problem:

Given a list of *n* objects (*n*'s Order of magnitude is 10^5), search for a given item very fast with a minimum of spacetime tradeoff. Current, unoptimized & prototype-y solution *takes too long and consumes too much RAM* (the optimization is *not* premature, that is).

There is not a primary key to sort against in the object, but it can be sorted to a certain degree, such as the following example, where the first column is sorted.

```
o1 => f, g, h
o2 => f, g, i
o3 => f, j, k
o4 => k, j, m
```

To date, the solution has been nested filters:

```
filter(test1, filter(test2, filter(test3, the_list)))
```

But that has been slow, since it involves n * (n - 1) * (n - 2) operations, which approximates to O(n^3) speed, and at least n*2 extra lists of references.

As a note, it would be vastly preferably to have an in-place search.

I haven't found a standard library for handling this. What is the typical solution to this problem?

Comment: Are your values unique, or can they occur multiple times in the list?

Comment: What's the nature of `test1` etc?

Comment: @juanco: each object is unique, but their attributes are often shared with a subset of the list in general

Comment: Can you give more information on the nature of the keys?  I'm thinking it may be possible to sort based on a concatenation of the keys.

Comment: @Sven: *So far*, they have been tests against internal attributes of the object.

Comment: @aaronstacy: each internal attribute is a string typically.

Comment: When you are searching for a given object, do you know the value of every internal attribute for that object?  If not, how do you know when you've found the right object?  If so, can't you concatenate the attribute values and use a hash table?

Comment: @Paul Nathan, I added an example to my answer. But if your class isn't hashable, you have to do something clever to get some kind of unique key, which then could be used in a `dict`.

Comment: You have a lot of data. You have complex queries. Databases were literally invented to solve this.

Comment: @Jochen: Agreed. Down the road (after the current release) I am thinking it would be appropriate to review SQLite's in-memory DB.

Comment: Shouldn't that take O(3n) time? I assume each test is O(1) time, each filter operation is on a list of size O(n), so its still linear time in the end. Or am I missing something?

Comment: `filter(test1, filter(test2, filter(test3, the_list)))` is the same as `[x for x in the_list if test1(x) and test2(x) and test3(x)]` - that is `O(n)`

Answer (score 2):

```
filter(test1, filter(test2, filter(test3, the_list)))
```

Firstly, this is O(n) time, not O(n^3) time. The time adds not multiply. The only this could be worse then that is if test3/test2/test1 are doing something odd, in which we should look at those.

If we suggest that each test? function takes 10 ms, then we have 10*3*10^5 ms = 50 minutes. If it was n^3, then we'd have (10*10^5)^3 = 31 million years. I'm pretty sure you are only one linear time, you just have a ton of data.

Replace filter with itertools.ifilter, it'll avoid generating the list. Instead, python will pull one item out of the list at a time, pass it through the three tests and give it to you if and only if it passes. It'll avoid the memory requirement and probably be faster as well.

You aren't going to be able to improve on O(n) time unless you use some indexing techniques. However, the applicability of indexing techniques depends on what you are doing inside the test1/test2/test3 functions. If you want help on that, show an example for those functions.

As other have noted, database were designed to solve these problems. You can make this faster only be reimplementing badly what databases already do for you.

Comment: O(n): I'm not convinced. Each filter is a O(n), no? So it's a triply nested loop; but the removals strip out a ton of data... no?

Comment: @Paul, The filters aren't nested. They are run one after the other. Filter takes an input list, runs through the list checking the results of test and returns a new list with the result. That list is then passed to the next function.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate the attribute values for each object to make unique keys.  You may have to pad the attributes out to the same length to guarantee uniqueness.  Construct a hash table to return the object that matches a key.

Comment: what's the space cost of a hash table with 100,000 elements?

Comment: No need to do all that. Use a `set`, which uses hashing and has its own way of dealing with collisions. The set is essentially a hash table. The only problem is if your elements are not hashable (which you can find out by trying to put them in a set).

Comment: @Paul Nathan: Probably 20 or 30 megabytes.  Is that really too much?

Comment: Probably not. I'm just very space-conscious: the current implementation breaks 1Gig RAM usage on a test dataset with only ~30K members.

Answer (score 0):

10^5 is not really that big a number of objects, even in-memory.  littletable is a little module I wrote as an experiment for simulating queries, pivots, etc. using just Python dicts.  One nice thing about littletable queries is that the result of any query or join is itself a new littletable Table.  Indexes are kept as dicts of keys->table objects, and index keys can be defined to be unique or not.

I created a table of 140K objects with 3 single letter keys, and then queried for a specific key. The time to build the table itself was the longest, the indexing and querying pretty fast.

```
from itertools import product
from littletable import Table,DataObject

objects = Table()
alphas = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
alphas += alphas.lower()
import time

print "building table", time.time()
objects.insert_many(
    DataObject(k1=k1, k2=k2, k3=k3, created=time.time())
        for k1,k2,k3 in product(alphas.upper(),alphas,alphas)
    )
print "table complete", time.time()
print len(objects)

print "indexing table", time.time()
for k in "k1 k2 k3".split():
    objects.create_index(k)
print "index complete", time.time()

print "get specific row", time.time()
matches = objects.query(k1="X", k2="k", k3="W")
for o in matches:
    print o
print time.time()
```

Prints:

```
building table 1309377011.63
table complete 1309377012.52
140608
indexing table 1309377012.52
index complete 1309377012.98
get specific row 1309377012.98
{'k3': 'W', 'k2': 'k', 'k1': 'X', 'created': 1309377011.9960001}
{'k3': 'W', 'k2': 'k', 'k1': 'X', 'created': 1309377012.4260001}
1309377013.0
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me one typical solution would be to use a database query.  Either SQL (raw or with some kind of ORM), or some kind of object database, maybe MongoDB?

Comment: There are two layers: one's the in-memory layer and one is the storage layer. The storage layer almost certainly can not be a database due to business constraints. The in-memory layer is what I'm focused on here: sqlite in-memory might be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in a CSV file, you could try sql2csv: https://sourceforge.net/projects/sql2csv/.

EDIT: Pardon my early-onset senility, I meant this project: https://github.com/ccoffey/sql4csv/wiki/Examples.

Comment: that is interesting, but it's a .net tool.

Comment: Oof! I meant this project: https://github.com/ccoffey/sql4csv/wiki/Examples, which I'm fairly sure is pure Python.